# Tapestry 5 - communication between two components

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a page in my Java + Tapestry 5 application, which contains two components - a Form and a Grid. The form field is use to filter the results displayed in the grid. The form is just a textfield which sets the value of the object A on which it is mapped. The grid is created from the object A. I need to send the right instance to the grid component from the form component. What is the best way to do this? I could do it the plain old java way by setting the object in the upper page, but there should be an cleaner way. I was thinking about environment annotation, but isn't that too heavy?

```
public class I1 {
    @Component
    private WFRFormFilter wfrFormFilter;

    @Component (parameters={ "wfrDataHolder=property:wfrFormFilter.wfrDataHolder" })
    private WFRResultTable wfrResultTable;
}

public class WFRFormFilter {
    @Inject
    private WFRService wfrservice;

    @Propperty
    @Persist
    private WFRDataHolder wfrDataHolder;

    @PageAttached
    void pageAttached() {
        if (wfrDataHolder == null) { 
            wfrDataHolder = new WFRDataHolder(); 
        }
    }

    @OnEvent(EventConstants.SUCCESS)
        void processMyForm() { }
}

public class WFRResultTable {
    @Parameter(defaultPrefix=BindingConstants.PROP)
    @Property
    private WFRDataHolder wfrDataHolder;

    @Inject
    private WFRService wfrservice;

    public List<WFRDataHolder> getResultTableData() {
        return wfrservice.getData(this.wfrDataHolder);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tapestry's parameters work bi-directionally: If you store your data in your page class (with `@Persist`) and pass it to your form component as a parameter, you can change its value in the form component, and that will be reflected to you page automatically: no calls to setters required.

So if you have your page and form component laid out like this:

```
 public class MyPage {

     @Component(parameters = "dataHolder=dataHolder")
     private MyForm formComponent;

     @Component(parameters = "dataHolder=dataHolder")
     private MyGrid gridComponent;

     @Persist
     @Property
     private MyDataHolder dataHolder;

}

public class MyFormComponent {

    @Parameter
    private MyDataHolder dataHolder;

    @OnEvent(EventConstants.SUCCESS)
    void formSubmitted() {
        this.dataHolder = new DataHolder(...);
    }

}
```

...then the proper value will always be present in the page, and thus also on the grid component.

Also see the [Component Parameters page in the Tapestry docs](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html), particularly the section "Parameters are Bi-Directional".

Comment: And what if the form component sends the dataHolder instance to the Environment and the Grid component uses the instance from the Environment? Are there any issues with that solution? Tapestry User Guide suggests it http://tapestry.apache.org/environmental-services.html

Comment: @Ondrej: That would be doable, but it would seem rather odd to use it in a case where normal parameters would do the job just fine.